# matplotlib and numpy archimedean spiral defined offset between rings of spiral and a defined length

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, data-science, data-analysis

```py
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# inputs
fromCords = (0, 0)  # (x, y), defaults to spawn
toCords = (4800, -5600)  # (x, y), these are the base coordinates
toPadding = 100  # because nobody will search 100 blocks near spawn, they will start from 100 to search
renderDistance = 8
viewDistance = renderDistance * 16 # 16 is the width of a chunk

# other
# distance = math.dist(fromCords, toCords) # will be used as the radius for the circle
distance = 500


def searchPattern(multiplier):  # represented by an archimedean spiral

    r = np.linspace(0, 250 * multiplier, 250)
    t = np.linspace(0, 250 + viewDistance * multiplier, 250)

    x = r*np.cos(np.radians(t))
    y = r*np.sin(np.radians(t))
    plt.plot(x, y)


def distanceRing(radius):  # represented by a circle
    theta = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, 100)
    x = radius*np.cos(theta)
    y = radius*np.sin(theta)
    plt.plot(x, y)


searchPattern(1)
distanceRing(distance)

plt.axis('equal')
plt.show()
```

### Goal

what I am trying to achieve is to have a variable which can determine a fixed distance between the turns of a spiral, view this image: https://ibb.co/Kmkq5P8. i want that all the shown distances in the image are corresponding to my selected variable, which in the above code, would be `viewDistance`. Another thing I need is a variable that determines the length of the spiral or how far it goes outward either by distance or radius, the current code does not allow for either, what is the best way to implement this?